# Linux source does not work in .sh file?

Tags: bash, sh

I have a .sh (`start_sim.sh`) and a .bash (`sim_sources.bash`) file. 
The `sim_sources.bash` file is called from within the `start_sim.sh` and should set an environment variable `$ROBOT` to a certain value. However the `ROBOT` variable never changes when I call `./start_sim.sh`. Is there a fundamental mistake in the way I am trying to do this?

`start_sim.sh` contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "sourcing sim_sources.bash..."
source /home/.../sim_sources.bash
echo "done."
```

`sim_sources.bash` contains:

```
# set the robot id
export ROBOT=robot
```

EDIT: Could you also propose a way to work around this issue? I would still need to set variables from with in the .bash file.

EDIT2:
Thanks for your replys!
Finally I ended up solving it with a screen and stuffing commands to it:

```
echo -n "starting screen..."
screen -dmS "sim_screen"
sleep 2
screen -S "sim_screen" -p 0 -X stuff "source /home/.../sim_sources.bash$(printf \\r)"
sleep 5
screen -S "sim_screen" -p 0 -X stuff "source /home/.../start_sim.sh$(printf \\r)"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Brian pointed out the variables are not available outside of the script.

Here a adapted script that shows this point:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "sourcing sim_sources.bash..."
. sim_sources.bash
echo $ROBOT
echo "done."
```

The workaround you are asking for is to start a new shell from the actual shell with the environmental values already set:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "sourcing sim_sources.bash..."
. sim_sources.bash
echo "done."
bash
```

This results in:

```
bash-4.1$ printenv | grep ROBOT
ROBOT=robot
```

Answer (score 6):

You're setting the `ROBOT` variable *in* the `start_sim.sh script`, but that's *not* available to parent processes (your spawning shell/command-prompt).

Exporting a variable e.g. `export ROBOT=robot` makes the variable available to the current process and child processes. When you invoke `./start_sim.sh` you're invoking a new process.

If you simply `source start_sim.sh` in your shell, that script runs as part of your shell process and then your variable will be available.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. But is there any way to work around this? I would need to set the variable from within the script. (There are actually a whole bunch of variables which should be set from the .bash file - however until now source has been called from within the .bashrc).

Answer (score 0):

I am on Ubuntu 16.04

I used /bin/sh instead of /bin/bash and it works !